# Solaris Convert Get Last Hour of Logs by Comparing the Timestamps

Tags: awk, solaris, nawk

I have a log that looks like this:

```
####<Sep 16, 2014 6:12:45 PM EST> <Notice> <StdErr> <myserver> <myinstance> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '17' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1410913515898> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)>
####<Sep 16, 2014 9:45:08 PM EST> <Notice> <StdErr> <myserver> <myinstance> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '17' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1410913515898> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)>
####<Sep 16, 2014 10:27:26 PM EST> <Notice> <StdErr> <myserver> <myinstance> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '17' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1410913515898> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)>
####<Sep 16, 2014 11:25:16 PM EST> <Notice> <StdErr> <myserver> <myinstance> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '17' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1410913515898> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)>
```

Let's say the time is currently 11:26 PM EST. I only want to get entries written in the last hour. I've previously used something like this:

```
nawk -F "<" -v MyDate=`TZ=MYT+6 date "+%b %d, %Y%l:%M:%S %Z"` ' {if ($2 > MyDate) print $2}'
```

but i'm getting the following error when attempting to run this:

```
nawk: syntax error at source line 1
  context is
     >>> 16, <<<
nawk: bailing out at source line 1
```

**How can I list the entries that were written in the last hour using the Solaris tools (NOT GNU)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set -vx` will set you free ;-)

When I execute

```
 print -- "####<Sep 16, 2014 11:25:16 PM EST> <Notice> <StdErr> <myserver> " \
 | awk -F "<" -v MyDate=`TZ=MYT+6 date "+%b %d, %Y%l:%M:%S %Z"` ' {if ($2 > MyDate) print $2}'
```

(I use ksh, and its print function is very handy, you can usually substitute `echo` for print in these sort of cases).

I get a very similar err msg

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>>  <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

When I issue the `set -vx`, I can see what is going to be executed AND what is being substituted for environment variables. Which shows me

```
1>awk -F '<' -v MyDate=Sep 16, 2014Sep 16 19:59:59:12 MYT ' {if ($2 > MyDate) print $2}'
```

Notice how 'Sep 16' is repeated?

I can do `man date` on my system, or as that can be problematic, I try each of the `%` args that I don't recognize and quickly find that for my version of `date`,

```
 date +%l
Sep 16 20:00
```

AND of course, the debug output shows me that I probably want to dbl-quote my input for the variable to awk, hence,

```
 awk -F "<" -v MyDate="`TZ=MYT+6 date '+%b %d, %Y:%M:%S %Z'`" ' {if ($2 > MyDate) print $2}'
```

should definitely be closer. If  you this doesn't fix it, then I'll set up a more detailed test.

Finally, I'd comment that I'm surprized that comparisons containing mixed format (Sep/MYT) date values work as you need, but I suppose translating `Sep 16, 2014 11:25:16 PM EST` into `201409162325165` is a bit of a headache.

P.S. Also using back-ticks for command substitution was branded as deprecated in the 'Kornshell programming language' published in 1995. Join the 90s and use `$( ... cmd ...)` command-substitution ;-)

IHTH

Comment: Nice, I was on pins and needles waiting for your final answer :) Works great, though I had to use nawk in Solaris. Thanks!

Comment: yep, `nawk` definitely is the way to go. Ironically, `awk` on Solaris's (seemingly) only error message is very similar to what I have included above. Glad that helped!

Comment: FYI: I miss the 90's ;)

Comment: LOL, me too. I'm throwing out my C programming books/mags this week, Nextstep stuff too, do you want them?